# ShellExecute crashes

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, shellexecute

I have a program which crashes on the `ShellExecute()` instruction. If I use the method `system()`, all works fine but I have read that `system()` was evil...

I'm using Visual Studio 2010 SP1.

So there is my function which calls ShellExecute:

```
ATC_GENERIC_API void __cdecl atcGenericLaunchGAG()
{
    HINSTANCE ret = ShellExecute( NULL, NULL, "MyExe.exe", NULL, "C:\\Opt\\", SW_SHOW );
    if( int(ret) > 32 )
    {
        //OK
        return;
    }
    //NOK
}
```

This is the error I have:

```
Unhandled exception at 0x640361c3 in Aneto Sol.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation reading location 0x0ba29bb0.
```

And the debugger breaks here:

```
void __cdecl operator delete(void* p)
{
#if !defined(_AFX_NO_DEBUG_CRT) && defined(_DEBUG)
    _free_dbg(p, _NORMAL_BLOCK);
#else
    free(p);
#endif
}
```

And that is my call stack:

```
mfc100d.dll!operator delete(void * p)  Line 347 + 0xc bytes C++
mfc100d.dll!operator delete[](void * p)  Line 360 + 0x9 bytes C++
mfc100d.dll!CPlex::FreeDataChain()  Line 43 + 0xf bytes C++
mfc100d.dll!CMapPtrToPtr::RemoveAll()  Line 87 C++
mfc100d.dll!CMapPtrToPtr::FreeAssoc(CMapPtrToPtr::CAssoc * pAssoc)  Line 147 C++
mfc100d.dll!CMapPtrToPtr::RemoveKey(void * key)  Line 252 C++
mfc100d.dll!CHandleMap::RemoveHandle(void * h)  Line 230 C++
```

Is there somebody who already has had this kind of error with ShellExecute or who can explain to me why ShellExecute crashes like that ? Thank you for your help.

Comment: This looks like your crash is somewhere else.  `ShellExecute` is in shell32.dll and does not use MFC at all, so the call stack doesn't match.

Comment: You can try using "ShellExecuteEx" and get the exact issue using GetLastError().

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Cory Nelson said, the error is not in the API itself, but in MFC. There might be a ShellExecute hook that causes your application to crash.

Answer (score 1):

I also experience similar thing with an MFC application. It worked in my laptop but after moving the code to my desktop it crashed VS2008 intermittently. Looking at the documentation of ShellExecute, it seems putting NULL to lpOperation is not so safe as it kind of auto picks the operation which is system specific. So I used _T("open") as the operation and so far it works fine.

p.s i was opening path in explorer and url.

Answer (score -2):

On Windows 20xx, 21xx, there is a problem calling ShellExecute.

I'm Delphi programmer and since WinXP I use syntax like this:

ShellExecute(Handle,'open',PChar('abcd.pdf'),nil,nil,SW_SHOWNORMAL);

to open PDF file in the default PDF viewer.

This worked fine from main application and from its DLL-s on WinXP, Win7 and Win10 1809.

On Windows 10 20H2 and 21H1 this method hangs main application if ShellExecute is inside DLL.

The way I found to solve this problem is add 2 lines after

ShellExecute(Handle,'open',PChar('abcd.pdf'),nil,nil,SW_SHOWNORMAL);

sleep(1200);

Application.ProcessMessages;

Regards
M

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow and thank you for trying to answer the question. Unfortunately your answer doesn't address the points in the original question and appears to be attracting down votes.

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow and thank you for trying to answer a user's question. Unfortunately your answer doesn't really address the points made in the original question and is attracting down votes. This is likely to happen if users think your answer doesn't help people searching for an answer to the specific problem raised.